# Retrieve visitor's email address

Tags: javascript, php, email, session, url

On my website, I'd like to retrieve the visitors' email addresses if they're logged in to their email inbox. How can I do that? (using PHP or Javascript).

And is it possible to retrieve their email address when they access the website by clicking the website's URL in an email they received.

(Say I send you an email containing the link to my website, if you click that link I want to store your email address!)

EDIT: I will make people (from and email list I already have) fill an anounymous survey form.. and I want to know if they filled it or not, if not I will resend the email.

Thank's in advance.

Comment: You'll have to explicitly ask the user for an email address. It would be a tremendous security problem otherwise.

Comment: so, they visit your site and you want to steal their user@hotmail.com address? Gee, that would never ever EVER get abused by spammers. no sirree!

Comment: You can customize the link for each recipient using data that will help you identify the user.

Comment: @MarcB It's often done for "Unsubscribe" links. They're not stealing your email address, since they already have it.

Comment: @Barmar: I think Marc B just meant that it's not possible to get user's mail address based solely on the fact that the user is logged into some (web)mail client as that's what the beginning of the question implies and he missed that lady_OC actually sends the mail.

Comment: @cascaval well i think its the opposite actually, for example she pays someone to send the emails  to a list they have and she now wants to get the list of emails for herself, in this case this is not feasible.

Comment: @JonidBendo: Well, we are all speculating while it's the OP that should have specified it. :-)

Comment: To be more clear, I will make them fill an anounymous survey form.. and I just want to know if they filled it or not, if not I will resend the email. No illegal use.

Comment: So are you sending the mails yourself or are you using some service provider (e.g. Mailjet) for that?

Comment: No, it's not for massive use! I'm sending through simple Google groups and mailing lists from my university.

Comment: Are you able to customize the link for each recipient? If you are sending it to a mailing list, you are not, which means that Barmar's answer won't help you.

Answer (score 3):

If you send them the email, you can put something in the URL that identifies them. You can put a hash code parameter in the URL, and then look that up in a database to get the corresponding email.

You should have a database table like:

```
CREATE TABLE customer_emails (
    hash CHAR(32) PRIMARY KEY,
    email VARCHAR(64)
);
```

When you send the emails, you add a row for each customer with a random hash code and their email. The email will contain a URL like:

```
http://yourdomain.com/somescript.php?hash=XYZ123ABC...
```

When they click on the link, the script does:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT email FROM customer_emails WHERE hash = :hash");
$stmt->bind_param(':hash', $_REQUEST['hash']);
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if ($row) {
    $email = $row['email'];
} else {
    // Resport that email is not found
}
```

Comment: Why would this get a downvote? It's exactly what people actually do.

Comment: Maybe he expected me to provide code that shows how to do it in detail.

Comment: what will the hash code retrieve then ? if I'm going to look up the email in the database?

Comment: I've added a code example.